# the numer of monic irreducible polynomials of degree $3$ in $\mathbb{F}_q$

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, ring-theory

I want to know how hany monic irreducible polynomials of degree $3$ there are in a field $\mathbb{F}_q$.

---

The whole number of monic polynomials of degree three is $q^3$.  Now I want to find out how many reducible polynomials there are among them. We can split any reducible $f$ in *one and only one* of the following ways:

$$
f \ = \ (X-\alpha)(X^2+bX+c) 
\qquad \text{or} \qquad
f \ = \ (X-\alpha)(X-\beta)(X-\gamma)
$$

1. In the first case, we take the number of monic irreducible polynomials of
   degree $2$ and multiply them by $q$, which gives us
   $\frac12(q^3-q^2)$.
2. To count the polynomials of the other kind, I thought it would be helpful to split up this set as
   $$
   \{(X-\alpha)^3 \ : \ \alpha \in \mathbb{F}_q \} 
   \quad \sqcup \quad
   \{ (X-\alpha)^2(X-\beta) \ : \ \alpha \neq \beta \ \}
   \quad \sqcup \quad 
   \{ (X-\alpha)(X-\beta)(X- \gamma) \ : \ \alpha, \beta, \gamma \text{ all differ }\}
   $$
   This would give us the following number of reducible polynomials of this shape:
   $$
   q + \frac12q(q-1)+\frac16q(q-1)(q-2)
   $$

Would you think that I will get the right answer if I'd calculate the value below?
$$
q^3 - \frac12(q^3-q^2) 
- \left( q + \frac12q(q-1)+\frac16q(q-1)(q-2) \right)
$$

Comment: Have you tried your formula out on some small cases where you can do the count manually?

Comment: You seem to be counting *monic* polynomials. Easy fix.

Comment: @André Nicolas, yes, that's right. I have added the word "monic" a few times to what I wrote. I hope that that makes things more insightful.

Comment: The general idea will work. There are some problems of detail. Check the number of monic irreducibles of degree $2$. For product of $3$ distinct, need to divide by $6$ not $3$.

Comment: As @AndréNicolas points out, I think the number of monic irreducibles of degree 2 is still wrong, but after fixing that you'll have the right answer. A simpler route is to use the fact that every monic irreducible of degree 3 is the minimal polynomial of exactly three elements of $\mathbb{F}_{q^3}$ that generate $\mathbb{F}_{q^3}$ as an extension of $\mathbb{F}_q$.